# Loop through list inside the list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a list named Models containing ID, Title, Variants. Variants is a list which contains another elements Id, ModelID, Title. 
My question is how to loop through the Variants list which is a sub list of Models.

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private List<ModelSearch> _list = new List<ModelSearch>();
    public Repository()
    {
        populateList();
    }

    private void populateList()
    {
        _list.Add(new ModelSearch
        {
            ID = 1,
            Title = "Scorpio",
            Variants = new List<Variant> { 
                new Variant { ID = 1, ModelID = 1, Title="scorpio1" },
                new Variant { ID = 2, ModelID = 1, Title="scorpio2" },
                new Variant { ID = 3, ModelID = 1, Title="scorpio3" }
            }
        });

        _list.Add(new ModelSearch
        {
            ID = 2,
            Title = "Bolero",
            Variants = new List<Variant> { 
                new Variant { ID = 1, ModelID = 2, Title="Bolero1" },
                new Variant { ID = 2, ModelID = 2, Title="Bolero2" },
                new Variant { ID = 3, ModelID = 2, Title="Bolero3" }
            }
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelSearch> GetAll()
    {
        return _list.AsEnumerable();

    }
}
```

Here is my Index.cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Variants.First().Title)
        </td>    
    </tr>
}
```

I want to display the corresponding variants also along with this table. How can I achieve this?

ModelSearchController.cs

```
public class ModelSearchController : Controller
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public ModelSearchController()
    {
        _repo = new Repository.Repository();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var modelList = _repo.GetAll(
        return View(modelList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another loop on the property in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to display all the variant titles, then you need an inner loop, for example here I am putting the titles in a `ul` element:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                @foreach(var variant in item.Variants)
                {
                    <li>@variant.Title</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```